# Concatenate strings without duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
id  v1  v2
1   a   b
1   a   d
2   c   e
2   d   e
2   f   g
```

I need to concatenate v1 and v2 using comma in each id group, however, if a value already exists in the group, do not concatenate it. So the output should look like:

```
id  v1  v2
1   a   b,d
2   c,d,f   e,g
```

I have done concatenation part, but I am not sure how to skip the duplicated values. Here is my code so far:

```
df.groupby(['id'])[['v1', 'v2']].agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x)).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap `x` around a set to get rid of the duplicates:

```
(df.groupby(['id'])[['v1', 'v2']]
   .agg(lambda x: ', '.join(set(x)))
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
   id       v1    v2
0   1        a  d, b
1   2  c, d, f  g, e
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you please elaborate how "set" works?

Comment: @Larry it’s one of the basic data types in Python. See [this](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)